# function (blurClass) NOT WORKING IN IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I can't get this plugin to function properly in IE....

Check out my homepage and look at the huge search field toward the top...

www.naturalskin.com

Whenever I refresh the screen the "blur" looses its function and I'm stuck with text.....

Here is the script that I place in an external js page: http://www.naturalskin.com/src/js/javascript/batches.js

```
jQuery.fn.hint = function (blurClass) {
  if (!blurClass) { 
    blurClass = 'blur';
  }

  return this.each(function () {
    // get jQuery version of 'this'
    var $input = jQuery(this),

    // capture the rest of the variable to allow for reuse
      title = $input.attr('title'),
      $form = jQuery(this.form),
      $win = jQuery(window);

    function remove() {
      if ($input.val() === title && $input.hasClass(blurClass)) {
        $input.val('').removeClass(blurClass);
      }
    }

    // only apply logic if the element has the attribute
    if (title) { 
      // on blur, set value to title attr if text is blank
      $input.blur(function () {
        if (this.value === '') {
          $input.val(title).addClass(blurClass);
        }
      }).focus(remove).blur(); // now change all inputs to title

      // clear the pre-defined text when form is submitted
      $form.submit(remove);
      $win.unload(remove); // handles Firefox's autocomplete
    }
  });
};
```

Erik

Comment: What version(s) of IE are giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `bind('blur',function(){})` instead of .blur(function(){});

olso use the trigger('blur') function istead of blur();

**Edited**

```
$input.bind('blur',function () {
        if (this.value === '') {
          $input.val(title).addClass(blurClass);
        }
      }).focus(remove).trigger('blur');
```

also a good tip if you are use ajax at any time use the .live() instead of .bind();
as this would lookup for new entries...

Comment: Where would place these changes in the script?